# key violation when inserting mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I have this SQL code which inserts into a database named `daily`. I regularly update the `daily` database like this:

```
INSERT INTO daily 
(SELECT * FROM dailytemp 
WHERE trim(`Point`) <>'' 
AND trim(`Point`) IN (Select trim(`Point`) FROM `data`));
```

I believe I am getting the error because both tables have id primary columns.

I want the data inserted, but a new id generated for any duplicate found.

I tried to list the columns names, but it's about 20 columns, which might make the process cumbersome.

What is my best option?

**Edit**

The table defination of daily and daily_temp are the same, all the folumns are varchar(100) with and id of (bigint)

```
id bigint
col1 varchar(100)
col2 varchar(100)
col3 varchar(100)
etc..
```

Comment: "the error". It would help if you post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Please post table definitions for `daily` and `dailytemp`

Comment: i made update, please check

Comment: Please confirm that `id` is `PRIMARY KEY` and whether there is any `UNIQUE` index on either table.

Comment: How ids are generated in `dailytemp`? Is it a persisted table?

Comment: the ids are autogenerated by mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution might be to use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and a separate table for sequencing (if you don't mind).

Sequence table

```sql
CREATE TABLE daily_seq(id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Now the trigger

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_daily_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON daily
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO daily_seq VALUES(NULL);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can insert whatever you want to daily, id value will replaced with unique auto incremented one.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7c0e/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you are certainly trying to insert a row with an `id` that already exists in `daily`.

If this does not pose any referential integrity issue, you could regenerate the `id`'s in `dailytemp` so that they do not overlap with any one in `daily`. This might do the trick:

```
SET @offset =  (SELECT MAX(id) FROM daily) - (SELECT MIN(id) FROM dalytemp) +1;
UPDATE dailytemp SET id = id + @offset;
```

Then try your `INSERT`.

If rows can be inserted into `daily` by another process than the one you described, or if for any reason a `id` is skipped in this table (eg. if the column is `AUTO_INCREMENT`), then the problem will reoccur. You may want to include this preliminary `UPDATE` in your daily procedure.

Answer (score 0):

i decided to use a stored proceedure to perform the action, listing all colums name instead of this headache

thanks to all those who helped. Another reason i did that was that i needed to insert a date for the daily table for each set of data inserted, so i created a date column for the dail table only

```sql
INSERT INTO daily (col1, col2, etc..., created) 
SELECT col1, col2, etc..., 'mydate' from daily_temp  WHERE 
trim(`Point`) <>'' AND trim(`Point`) IN 
(Select trim(`Point`) FROM `data`));
```

thanks all